# How to reference an instance in class A from class B

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, class, instance

I have four classes: *document*, *topPanel*, *listPanel* and *detailsPanel*. In this particular example the *topPanel* checks when to *advanceDay* (a function in *document*). When *advanceDay* is activated *document* tells *topPanel* to *calculateDate*, *listPanel* to *sortList* and *detailsPanel* to *refreshDetails*. *calculateDate* then works out the date and tries to update a dynamic text field but can't find it's instance. Similar problems occur in regards to *sortList* and *refreshDetails*.

**topPanel:**

```
function advanceLoop(a:Event)
{
    loopCounter +=  simSpeed;
    if ((loopCounter >= 24))
    {
        loopCounter = 0;
        document.advanceDay();
    }
}

public static function calculateDate()
{
    ... // sets moonCounter and yearCounter using day
    date.text = document.prettyNumbers[moonCounter] + " moon of the year " + yearCounter + " B.C.";
}
```

**document:**

```
public static var prettyNumbers:Array = ["Zeroth","First","Second","Third","Fourth","Fifth","Sixth","Seventh","Eighth","Ninth","Tenth","Eleventh","Twelfth","Thirteenth","Fourteenth"];

...

public static function advanceDay()
{
    topPanel.day++;
    topPanel.calculateDate();           
    listPanel.sortList();
    detailsPanel.refreshDetails();
}
```

The error returned:

```
Line 278 1120: Access of undefined property date.
```

*date* is the name of an instance (dynamic text field) within topPanel. The *calculateDate* function works perfectly when the *advanceDay* function is in the *topPanel* class and the "public static" bit is removed. Thanks for reading and I hope you can help!

Comment: Accessing something with a class from another class is a bad idea. You normally want to do that in your main class (`document` in this case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functions marked static can only access properties which are static themselves. 'date', I believe, isn't a static member variable which is why the compiler is saying it can't find a 'date' with necessary 'static' qualifier'